# EditText dimensions change if I use color as a background?

Tags: android, android-edittext

EditText views shrink in size if I use this to change their color:

```
    android:background="@android:color/white"
```

Why is this happening? How can I make them white and maintain their size? I dont like the default grey look they have.
Same question regarding spinners...

Comment: Can you upload image or paste entire code ? What are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1、You can set minHeight attribute in xml layout 
2、you can set a white background image that has the same height with the system edittext's backgound image.
3、you can just set background as transparent color and a white background to it's parent view.

Comment: Which method did you use? I suggest you use method 2 use a bordered background nine-patch image.

Comment: I used method 1 because it was the most simple :) If I have used an image, I should have provided all resolutions versions and then if I wanted to change the size or something else, I would have had to edit them all and I dont think that is flexible. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: You can use a shape:
create edit_text_bg.xml in drawable folder
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>   
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">   
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />   
    <corners android:radius="3dip"/>  
    <stroke    
        android:width="1dip"    
        android:color="#728ea3" />   
</shape>
and android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bg"

Answer (score 0):

- try to give fixed width and height
         or
  your problem could be solved by this too:
  What should you do is to create a 9 patch image for edittext and set that image as edit text background. You can create 9 patches using this website [click here](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html)

Try use it as edittext background and you will get an idea.Right click the image and select "save image as". When you save the image dont forget to give its extension as "9.png"