# Why does removing background of containing EditText increase row height?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-tablelayout

Does anybody know why my table row height increases when I remove the background property of containing EditText?

```
<TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="1,3" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tr3a"
            android:padding="2.5dp"
            android:background="@color/col1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lab_bookname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/bookname" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/bookname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:background="@color/white" // FOR VIEW 1, I REMOVE THIS LINE, NO OTHER CHANGE
                android:hint="@string/definputtext2" />

        </TableRow>
```

[image]

Comment: change the height by dp ie use `android:layout_height="15dp"`

Comment: why layout_height should act differently with and without background?

Comment: I dont know but This issue had faced me too but setting the height helped me !

Comment: hmmm, I just noticed the same ... but it causes the clickable area of EditText to shrink vertically .. also I don't want to specify the height explicitly unless I have to ... thanks anyway, may be ultimately I Have to follow your suggestion ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Height changes because by setting a custom background you are replacing the EditText default background, which might not be just a color resource.

Check these similar questions:

[Problem with EditText background (android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625633/problem-with-edittext-background-android)

[EditText dimensions change if I use color as a background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051194/edittext-dimensions-change-if-i-use-color-as-a-background)